# Concat two dynamic strings using Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Is it possible to concat two dynamic strings using Data Binding?

My code looks like:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_activity_profile_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image_view_activity_profile_small_photo"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@={userdata.firstName+' '+userdata.lastName}"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

,but it is not the correct way : 
Error:(52, 42) The expression (firstNameUserdataCha) + (lastNameUserdata) cannot cannot be inverted: Two way binding with operator + supports only a single dynamic expressions.

Comment: set your textview in your java code with setText.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try it like this instead

```
android:text='@{userdata.firstName+" "+userdata.lastName}'
```

or alternately...

```
android:text='@{String.format("%s %s", userdata.firstName, userdata.lastName)}'
```

Comment: This is right. It is not possible to use two-way data binding (`@={...}` instead of `@{...}`) with string concatenation. A third (and better) option is to use resource formatting to support multiple languages: `android:text="@{@string/name(userdata.firstName, userdata.lastName)}"`

Answer (score 11):

#### Below is recommended way.

It is also useful when you have **localization/ multi language**

Use string resource like this.

```
android:text="@{@string/generic_name(user.firstName,user.lastName)}"
```

and make string resource in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="generic_name">first name : %1$s and last name : %2$s</string>
```

You can check many other ways in **[this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640344/6891563)**

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile since you're using two-way data binding. Android DataBinding generated class won't be able to assign back the value of the `TextView` to `userData` since there are two variables used. You can use one-way data binding instead:

`android:text='@{userData.firstName + " " + userData.lastName}'`

If you really want to use two-way data binding, then make a custom converter for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        <TextView
                        ..........
                        android:text='@{String.format("%s %s","+91", userInfo.mobile)}'
                        .............. />
```

## try this if you want add multiple string

```
android:text='@{String.format("%s %s","+91", userInfo.mobile)}'
```

output: +91 0000000000